# Is joining 3 columns in a WHERE clause and a LIKE achievable?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to do a query like this using MySQL in Java. I wanted to make a search bar similar to facebook that doesn't need a specifc column to search from but searches through many columns.

```
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    String key = searchbar.getText();
    Connection con = Connect();

    String sql="Select * from table1 WHERE Surname,Middlename,Firstname LIKE ?";
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setString(1, "%" +key+ "%");


       ResultSet result =  statement.executeQuery();
```

How do I achieve as such? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current syntax won't work, but there is no reason why you cannot just repeat the `LIKE` expression three times, once for each column:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Surname LIKE ? OR ";
sql +=       "Middlename LIKE ? OR Firstname LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, "%" + key + "%");
statement.setString(2, "%" + key + "%");
statement.setString(3, "%" + key + "%");
```

Edit from @SBF I have ORed together the terms in your `WHERE` clause.  If you really want records where all three names match the key, then replace `OR` with `AND`.

Comment: `OR`ing would be better I think